# Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change

Tags: javascript, object, copy

I am copying `objA` to `objB`

```
const objA = { prop: 1 }, 
const objB = objA; 
objB.prop = 2;
console.log(objA.prop); // logs 2 instead of 1
```

same problem for Arrays

```
const arrA = [1, 2, 3], 
const arrB = arrA; 
arrB.push(4); 
console.log(arrA.length); // `arrA` has 4 elements instead of 3.
```

Comment: This might help if u're not using jQuery:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 167, accepted):

It is clear that you have some misconceptions of what the statement `var tempMyObj = myObj;` does.

In JavaScript objects are passed and assigned by reference (more accurately the value of a reference), so `tempMyObj` and `myObj` are both references to the same object.

Here is a simplified illustration that may help you visualize what is happening

```
// [Object1]<--------- myObj

var tempMyObj = myObj;

// [Object1]<--------- myObj
//         ^ 
//         |
//         ----------- tempMyObj
```

As you can see after the assignment, both references are pointing to the same object.

You need to **create a copy** if you need to modify one and not the other.

```
// [Object1]<--------- myObj

const tempMyObj = Object.assign({}, myObj);

// [Object1]<--------- myObj
// [Object2]<--------- tempMyObj
```

**Old Answer:**

Here are a couple of other ways of creating a copy of an object

Since you are already using jQuery:

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, myObj);
```

With vanilla JavaScript

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

var newObject = clone(myObj);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: @JAAulde, thanks for updating the answers post your update to the question. I am not sure I would have caught that.

Comment: No problem! When I make such an extensive edit to a question which has been answered, I try to follow up. :)

Comment: It might be worth noting this seems to start rearing its head when you create your own objects (e.g. `let a={}; let b=a; b.blah=1;console.log(a)` ). I'm guessing many novices (like me) won't notice this because many commands output a new object for us (e.g. map/filter/etc). I am struggling to understand why anyone would sanely want the current behavior...

Comment: `Object.assign({}, myObj);` didn't create a copy for me. Instead `var tempMyObj = Object.create(myObj);` worked.

Comment: This answer should include how to do this with arrays as well: `const arrB = arrA.slice();`, `const arrB = Array.from(arrA);`, or `const arrB = [ ...arrA ];`.

Comment: Note! ^ if your array consists of objects, then the above will not work! The original object will still be modified (the arrays themselves are different, but the object references are the same)

Comment: @robbmj What happens actually on the memory side? Is the same memory allocation assigned to temp variable right? That's why value is changing when changing temp/original one. right? Is my understand correct?

Answer (score 37):

To sum it all up, and for clarification, there's four ways of copying a JS object.

1. A **normal copy**. When you change the original object's properties, the copied object's properties will change too (and vice versa).

```js
const a = { x: 0}
const b = a;
b.x = 1; // also updates a.x
```

2. A **shallow copy**. Top level properties will be unique for the original and the copied object. Nested properties will be shared across both objects though. Use the spread operator `...{}` or `Object.assign()`.

```js
const a = { x: 0, y: { z: 0 } };
const b = {...a}; // or const b = Object.assign({}, a);

b.x = 1; // doesn't update a.x
b.y.z = 1; // also updates a.y.z
```

3. A **deep copy**. All properties are unique for the original and the copied object, even nested properties. For a deep copy, serialize the object to JSON and parse it back to a JS object.

```js
const a = { x: 0, y: { z: 0 } };
const b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)); 

b.y.z = 1; // doesn't update a.y.z
```

4. A **full deep copy**. With the above technique, property values that are not valid in JSON (like functions) will be discarded. If you need a deep copy and keep nested properties that contain functions, you might want to look into a utility library like `lodash`.

```js
import { cloneDeep } from "lodash"; 
const a = { x: 0, y: { z: (a, b) => a + b } };
const b = cloneDeep(a);

console.log(b.y.z(1, 2)); // returns 3
```

5. Using `Object.create()` does create a new object. The properties are shared between objects (changing one also changes the other). The difference with a normal copy, is that properties are added under the new object's prototype `__proto__`. When you *never* change the original object, this could also work as a shallow copy, but I would suggest using one of the methods above, unless you specifically need this behaviour.

Comment: Note that using `JSON.stringify` to deep copy an object will discard any values that are not valid in JSON (like functions) and any which are not enumerable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that `...{}` is a shallow copy and does not make unique copies of the nested objects. I was running into this problem and not sure why my original value was being modified!

Answer (score 31):

deep clone object with JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify

```
// Deep Clone
obj = { a: 0 , b: { c: 0}};
let deepClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

refrence: [this article](https://www.codementor.io/junedlanja/copy-javascript-object-right-way-ohppc777d)

**Better reference**: [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-javascript-a0a04104ab5c)

Comment: this one is great but it doesnt clone functions inside the object

Comment: cloning object which includes multi levels or includes functions is a complicated process, you should use lodash (https://lodash.com/) library to help you in this process or make your own algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

Try using the create() method like as mentioned below.

```
var tempMyObj = Object.create(myObj);
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Though your answer is correct and absolutely fits here. But there's a downside of using Object.create(). It adds the properties to dunder proto \__proto__ of the object and not the object. Object.assign() adds the properties to the object.

Answer (score 7):

use three dots to spread object in the new variable

```
const a = {b: 1, c: 0};
let d = {...a};
```

Comment: Cloud you develop a little bit your answer to explain the reason why spread operator are also working? It may help others understand your answer

Comment: this will copy only the top-level properties of the object but if the object has a nested object will still refer to the original nested objects, so this approach will not copy the nested object, it will only include the original nested object.

Answer (score 6):

Try using [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend):

> If, however, you want to preserve both of the original objects, you
>   can do so by passing an empty object as the target:
>
> `var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);`

---

```
var tempMyObj = $.extend({}, myObj);
```

Comment: bingo, that was what i about to write.. :)

Comment: JavaScript now has a similar function built-in, [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Example usage: `Object.assign({}, myObj)`.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane - this got me what I needed, huge thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As I couldn't find **this code** anywhere around suggested answers for shallow copy/cloning cases, I'll leave this here:

```js
// shortcuts
const {
  create,
  getOwnPropertyDescriptors,
  getPrototypeOf
} = Object;

// utility
const shallowClone = source => create(
  getPrototypeOf(source),
  getOwnPropertyDescriptors(source)
);

// ... everyday code ...

const first = {
  _counts: 0,
  get count() {
    return ++this._counts;
  }
};

first.count;  // 1

const second = shallowClone(first);

// all accessors are preserved
second.count; // 2
second.count; // 3
second.count; // 4

// but `first` is still where it was
first.count;  // just 2
```

The main difference compared to `Object.assign` or `{...spread}` operations, is that this utility will preserve all accessors, symbols, and so on, in the process, including the inheritance.

Every other solution in this space seems to miss the fact cloning, or even copying, is not just about properties values as retrieved once, but accessors and inheritance might be more than welcome in daily cases.

For everything else, use native `structuredClone` method or [its polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ungap/structured-clone)

Answer (score 2):

This might be very tricky, let me try to put this in a simple way. When you "copy" one variable to another variable in javascript, you are not actually copying its value from one to another, you are assigning to the copied variable, a **reference to the original object**. To actually make a copy, you need to create a new object use

**The tricky part is because there's a difference between assigning a new value to the copied variable and modify its value.** When you **assign a new value** to the copy variable, you are getting rid of the reference and assigning the new value to the copy, however, if you only **modify the value** of the copy (without assigning a new value), you are modifying the copy and the original.

Hope the example helps!

```js
let original = "Apple";
let copy1 = copy2 = original;
copy1 = "Banana";
copy2 = "John";

console.log("ASSIGNING a new value to a copied variable only changes the copy. The ogirinal variable doesn't change");
console.log(original); // Apple
console.log(copy1); // Banana
console.log(copy2); // John 

//----------------------------

original = { "fruit" : "Apple" };
copy1 = copy2 = original;
copy1 = {"animal" : "Dog"};
copy2 = "John";

console.log("\n ASSIGNING a new value to a copied variable only changes the copy. The ogirinal variable doesn't change");
console.log(original); //{ fruit: 'Apple' }
console.log(copy1); // { animal: 'Dog' }
console.log(copy2); // John */

//----------------------------
// HERE'S THE TRICK!!!!!!!

original = { "fruit" : "Apple" };
let real_copy = {};
Object.assign(real_copy, original);
copy1 = copy2 = original;
copy1["fruit"] = "Banana"; // we're not assiging a new value to the variable, we're only MODIFYING it, so it changes the copy and the original!!!!
copy2 = "John";


console.log("\n MODIFY the variable without assigning a new value to it, also changes the original variable")
console.log(original); //{ fruit: 'Banana' } <====== Ops!!!!!!
console.log(copy1); // { fruit: 'Banana' }
console.log(copy2); // John 
console.log(real_copy); // { fruit: 'Apple' } <======== real copy!
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the same problem with arrays then here is the solution

```
let sectionlist = [{"name":"xyz"},{"name":"abc"}];
let mainsectionlist = [];
for (let i = 0; i < sectionlist.length; i++) {
     mainsectionlist[i] = Object.assign({}, sectionlist[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript objects are passed as reference and they using shallow comparison so when we change any instance of the object the same changes is also referenced to the main object.

To ignore this replication we can stringify the JSON object.

example :-

```
let obj = {
   key: "value"
}
function convertObj(obj){
   let newObj = JSON.parse(obj);
   console.log(newObj)
}
convertObj(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would copy objA to objB without referencing objA

```
let objA = { prop: 1 }, 
let objB = Object.assign( {}, objA )   
objB.prop = 2;

console.log( objA , objB )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can now use structuredClone() for deep object clones :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

```
const newItem = structuredClone(oldItem);
```

Answer (score -3):

Serialize the original object into JSON and Deserialize to another object variable of same type. This will give you copy of object with all property values. And any modification to original object will not impact the copied object.

```
string s = Serialize(object); //Serialize to JSON
//Deserialize to original object type
tempSearchRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OriginalObjectType>(s);
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript specific question related to how JavaScript handles references, why is your code example .NET?