# Changes in Cloned Object affects the original Object as well

Tags: javascript

Despite answers provided in  [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change)

and

[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

I have issues in cloning object.

In this fiddle you will notice that changes in the childObject affects the parent as well
https://jsfiddle.net/vpmerr5k/

```
var obj = { id: { '1': { entry: '1', rowCount: 2 },
 '2': { entry: '2', rowCount: 3 },
 '3': { entry: '3', rowCount: 4 },
 '4': { entry: '4', rowCount: 5 },
 '6': { entry: '6', rowCount: 7 },
 },ip_address: { '200.235.118.96': { entry: '200.235.118.96', rowCount: 2 },
 '1.57.134.207': { entry: '1.57.134.207', rowCount: 3 },
 '116.202.63.225': { entry: '116.202.63.225', rowCount: 4 },
 '176.128.148.225': { entry: '176.128.148.225', rowCount: 5 },
 '144.176.153.177': { entry: '144.176.153.177', rowCount: 6 },
 }
}
var slicedObj = Object.assign({}, obj); 
Object.keys(slicedObj).map(function(keys){  
 Object.keys(slicedObj[keys]).map(function(param){
  if(!(slicedObj[keys][param]["rowCount"]>0 && slicedObj[keys][param]["rowCount"]<4)) {
     delete(slicedObj[keys][param])
 }  })})
console.log(obj)
```

But In this fiddle the changes dont affect the parentObject (removed the map function)
https://jsfiddle.net/5oxducfy/

```
var obj = { id: { '1': { entry: '1', rowCount: 2 },
 '2': { entry: '2', rowCount: 3 },
 '3': { entry: '3', rowCount: 4 },
 '4': { entry: '4', rowCount: 5 },
 '6': { entry: '6', rowCount: 7 },
 },
ip_address: { '200.235.118.96': { entry: '200.235.118.96', rowCount: 2 },
 '1.57.134.207': { entry: '1.57.134.207', rowCount: 3 },
 '116.202.63.225': { entry: '116.202.63.225', rowCount: 4 },
 '176.128.148.225': { entry: '176.128.148.225', rowCount: 5 },
 '144.176.153.177': { entry: '144.176.153.177', rowCount: 6 },
 }
}
var slicedObj = Object.assign({}, obj); 
Object.keys(slicedObj).map(function(keys){
     delete(slicedObj["id"])
})
console.log(obj)
```

Is my interpretation right? (Issue being with map function) 
Is so please suggest a way out.

Comment: Except for the academic effect, why are you writing your own object cloning function?

Comment: Sry friend, I dont see any cloning function. I just have a usecase where I need to create child Objects from parent Object. I want to use the cloning the object and editing it later approach.