# JavaScript getImageData Canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

```
// Set colour of light bulb
function set_bulb_colour(img_id, rgb_colour) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var data = image_data.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      if (data[i + 3] == 0) {
        continue;
      }

      // If the pixel is yellow set it to the new colour
      if (data[i] > 200 && data[i + 2] < 100) {
        data[i] = rgb_colour[0];
        data[i + 1] = rgb_colour[1];
        data[i + 2] = rgb_colour[2];
      }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);

    $('img#living_room_light_emoji').attr('src', canvas.toDataURL());
  }

  img.src = 'images/light_bulb.png';
}
```

I have a question about the code i have above if anyone knows the answer. The code works. It changes all the yellow pixels in a light bulb image to a rgb colour passed in. I get an object from `getImageData`. I then get the data calling `.data` on that. I modify the pixels in the `data` variable. But when i redraw the image using `putImageData`, i put the object `image_data` back in instead of the ‘data’ that i was modifing. How does that work, does the `data` variable somehow point to the object in `image_data`?

So what im asking is, by reading that code it looks like you take a copy of `image_data`’s `data` by calling `.data` and store it in a variable called `data`. To me modifiying `data` would not modify `image_data`. But it does. How does this work? When you use `image_data` to redraw it has the modified `data`. Does `data` point to `image_data`? I know how you could make this happen in C but didn't think it would work like this in javascript

Comment: Indeed, `var data = image_data.data;` does not create a copy. The variable `data` and the property `image_data.data` refer to the same object.

Comment: There are tons of duplicates of this questions. All primirive values (number, strings, ...) are copied when passed around. All other types (arrays, objects, ...) are not, only a reference to their underlying data is passed. So `data` and `image_data.data` are both pointing to the same array in memory. Changes to one is reflected on the other.

Comment: ... the answer to the third duplicate question features a very interesting [**illustration**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29050089/).

Comment: Thanks guys, I just do JavaScript at home for my own stuff so haven't a lot of experience, helpful comments, sorry about the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does that work, does the ‘data’ variable somehow point to the
>   object in ‘image_data’?

The short answer is yes.

The longer answer can be found here: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Basically, it's "call-by-sharing" (as opposed to pass-by-value or pass-by-reference). If you change the "original", the changes will not persist down but changes to "references" will persist back to the original.