# Eloquent Javascript LifeLikeTerrarium clone

Tags: javascript, inheritance, clone

I am going through Marijn Haverbeke's Eloquent Javascript and am having some trouble understanding a section of the LifeLikeTerrarium example. Specifically the code below:

```
function clone(object){
    function OneShotConstructor(){}
        OneShotConstructor.prototype = object;
        return new OneShotConstructor();                
}
```

Which is called by the constructor for LifeLikeTerrarium:

```
function LifeLikeTerrarium(plan){
    Terrarium.call(this, plan);
}           
LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype = clone(Terrarium.prototype);
LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype.constructor = LifeLikeTerrarium;
```

My understandig is that LifeLikeTerrarium should inherit from Terrarium and this code is trying to make that happen. My uncertainty is about how it achieves this.

- Does doing the 'Terrarium.call(this, plan) pass the data to the Terrarium constructor as if you had called Terrarium(plan) within the context of the inheritence?
- What is the purpose of calling clone(object)? How is this different from saying "LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype = Terrarium.prototype?
- What is the purpose of assigning LifeLikeTerrarium's constructor to itself?

I feel like I understand the rest of the code but this seems like a pretty crucial section. Would really appreciate anyone who is willing to break it down for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### Does doing the `Terrarium.call(this, plan)` pass the data to the `Terrarium` constructor as if you had called `Terrarium(plan)` within the context of the inheritence?

Yes. **`Function#call`** calls the function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually. Meaning we specify the `this` inside the called function to be whatever object we want. `Terrarium.call(this, plan)` passes our current `this` (which will be an instance of `LifeLikeTerrarium`) to the call to `Terrarium`. If `Terrarium` assigns something or modifies `this` inside itslef, the `this` it modifies will be what we passed to it using `call`, here the current instance of `LifeLikeTerrarium`. The rest of the parameters to `call` are all passed along to the called function as individual paramaters.

**Demonstration:**

```js
function foo(a, b) {
    this.sum = a + b;
}

var obj = {};

foo.call(obj, 5, 7);                // obj will be the 'this' used inside foo.
                                    // 5 and 7 will be the values of foo's arguments a and b, respectively

console.log(obj);                   // et voilà
```

> #### What is the purpose of calling `clone(object)`? How is this different from saying `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype = Terrarium.prototype`?

We don't want to do `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype = Terrarium.prototype`. Ever. Because `LifeLikeTerrarium` is most likely going to have methods of its own that [**we don't want added**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29050004/9867451) to `Terrarium` as well. Imagine we add a method to `LifeLikeTerrarium`'s prototype called `foo`. `foo` will also be available to `Terrarium`. Even worse, `foo` could replace `Terrarium`'s own method `foo`, if it happens to have one:

```js
function Terrarium() {  }
Terrarium.prototype.sayHi = function() {
    console.log("Hi! I'm Terrarium");
}

function LifeLikeTerrarium() {  }
LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype = Terrarium.prototype;    // now LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype and Terrarium.prototype are both referencing the same object, changes to one are reflected on the other
LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype.sayHi = function() {      // Terrarium.prototype.sayHi is gone for ever. May it rest in peace.
    console.log("Hi! I'm LifeLikeTerrarium");
}

var terrarium = new Terrarium();
terrarium.sayHi();                                    // wrong wrong wrong
```

As you can see, this is very bad. Depending on what the method does, it could even throw an error and break the execution (if for example the new method uses properties that aren't in the original object `Terrarium`):

```js
function Terrarium() {  }
Terrarium.prototype.sayHi = function() {
    console.log("Hi! I'm an abstract Terrarium that doesn't have a name");
}

function LifeLikeTerrarium(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype = Terrarium.prototype;
LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype.sayHi = function() {
    console.log("Hi! I'm " + this.name.toUpperCase());  // b.. b.. but Terrarium doen't have a property called name. Let's see what will happen. Maybe it'll work 
}

var terrarium = new Terrarium();
terrarium.sayHi();                                      // Surprise! You got mail, I mean an error
```

In addition to this, we, at the very least, will be poluting the original object with methods that it won't even need or use:

```js
function Terrarium() {  }

function LifeLikeTerrarium() {  }
LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype = Terrarium.prototype;
LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype.sayHi = function() {      // now Terrarium has a method called sayHi although it originally didn't have one.
    console.log("Hi!");
}

var terrarium = new Terrarium();
terrarium.sayHi();                                    // Want proof? Here you go.
```

How do we get arround this? The answer is: We don't assign `Terrarium.prototype` to `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype` so that both prototypes reference the same object. No, we assign to `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype` a plain new object that has its prototype set to `Terrarium.prototype`. The new plain object (which is the result of `new OneShotConstructor()`) will act as `LifeLikeTerrarium`'s own prototype. That plain object will have its prototype set to `Terrarium.prototype` which causes `Terrarium`'s methods to be available to `LifeLikeTerrarium`, a phenomenon that goes by the name of *"Inheritance"*. Here is a diagram of the difference between the two ways:

**`LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype = Terrarium.prototype`:**

```
Terrarium.prototype ---------------------> {
                               |                ...
                               |                ...
                               |           }
                               |
LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype ---/
```

**`LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype = clone(Terrarium.prototype)`:**

```
Terrarium.prototype ---------------------> {
                               |                ...
                               |                ...
                               |           }
                               |
                               \------------------------------\
                                                              |
LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype -------------> {                  |
                                                ...           |
                                                ...           |
                                                prototype: ---/
                                           }
```

As you can see, in the first diagram, both `Terrarium.prototype` and `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype` are referencing the same object. Whereas in the second diagram each is referencing it's own object: `Terrarium.prototype` is referencing its own object which is defined somewhere in your code and `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype` is referencing an instance of `OneShotConstructor` (which is an empty object because the constructor is an empty one). Another benifit is that `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype`'s prototype is referencing `Terrarium.prototype` (made possible because of `OneShotConstructor.prototype = object;`). This creates a nice prototype chain that lets methods of `Terrarium` be available to `LifeLikeTerrarium` if the latter doesn't want to have its own, and if it does (want to have its own), that will be totally fine because they won't replace `Terrarium`'s, they'll just shadow them. And this is the essence of [**prototype inheritence**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

> #### What is the purpose of assigning `LifeLikeTerrarium`'s constructor to itself?

This already has an answer here: [Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor)

Comment: Thank you so much for that in depth explanation. One point of clarification I am still struggling with is how the OneShotConstructor object avoids affecting the Terrarium prototype. If OneShotConstructor is pointing at Terrarium.prototype and LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype is pointing at OneShotConstructor, how do they not encounter the same problem?

Comment: @Yusif_Nurizade `OneShotConstructor` instance is not pointing at `Terrarium.prototype`, It just has a property that points to it, that property's name is `prototype`. Look at it this way: `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype === new OneShotConstructor() === { prototype: Terrarium.prototype }`. So when you assign, for example, a function called `foo` to `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype` it becomes: `{ foo: function() { ... }, prototype: Terrarium.prototype }`. `Terrarium.prototype` is unaffected by this as you can see. You would affect `Terrarium.prototype` if you do `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype.prototype`

Comment: @Yusif_Nurizade in the first diagram `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype === Terrarium.prototype`. Whereas in the second diagram `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype !== Terrarium.prototype`, it's `LifeLikeTerrarium.prototype.prototype === Terrarium.prototype`

Comment: @Yusif_Nurizade **notice the double `.prototype.prototype`?** (the chain).

Comment: Yes that clarifies things very well. It appears the OneShotConstructor acts as a middleman so that when new methods are added/changed for LifeLikeTerrarium, they do not affect Terrarium. Thanks again for taking the time to break it down for me!