# Jquery changing value at original array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, data-binding

I build a simple cart.

First I have an array of items called vouchers - like:

```
"[{"id":"108","name":"Gourmet Tasting Menu for Two","price":"85.00","photo":"1102/KtOdtlg.jpg"},{"id":"109","name":"Sampler Menu for Two","price":"60.00","photo":"1102/YrLaHlg.jpg"},{"id":"127","name":"&pound;100 Gift Voucher","price":"100.00","photo":"1102/qexxflg.jpg"}]"
```

and `cart = [];`

Now I have a function to add items to CART array:

```
//with this function based on ID I find object into vouchers array and push that into CART array


    function addItemToCart (id) {
        qty = $('#qty').val();
        var data = $.grep(vouchers, function(e){ return e.id == id; });
        data = data[0];
        data.voucher_id = id;
        data.to = $('#to').val();
        data.from = $('#from').val();
        data.isGift = 0;
        data.recipient_email = $('#recipient_email').val();
        if (data.recipient_email != '') {
            data.isGift = 1;
        }
        data.message = $('#message').val();
        data.qty = qty;
        data.total = qty*data.price;
        cart.push(data);

    };
```

and this works good and add Item into the CART but also change values in vouchers array. Why? WHy `data.total` is added into the object in vouchers array...

I need vouchers array to be with unchangeable values... Why when I change values this way it binds values into vouchers array.

Comment: *I have an array*... you mean *an invalid String*?

Comment: this is stringified array

Comment: you need a deep copy of your array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change)

Comment: How to make a deep copy ?

Comment: see the answer it may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Simply clone any type of array with:

```
[].concat(data);
```

since concat may not work in some IE browsers, you can use this:

```
new_array = old_array.slice(0);
```

or you can use

```
var clonedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalArray))

var clonedArray = $.map(originalArray, function (obj) {
                  return $.extend({}, obj);
              });
```

Comment: so I need to change line data = data[0]; with your code ?

Comment: I got Uncaught TypeError: data.slice is not a function

Comment: you need a deep copy when you are using a grep it is searching in same array. due to reference you are changing your original value.

Comment: But GREP isn't supposed to change the original array?