# Assign a Value to an Object inside another object that has dynamically assigned keys

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, assign

I have an object with the numerical months as the keys for other objects, containing years for keys and Zeros for the initial values.

```
MonthRow : {   
   1 : {2017:0,2018:0},
   2 : {2017:0,2018:0},
   3 : {2017:0,2018:0},
   4 : {2017:0,2018:0},
   5 : {2017:0,2018:0},
   6 : {2017:0,2018:0}
}
```

After a query I am using the following code to set the values for each of these objects

```
 Object.keys(MainData.MonthRow).forEach(function(key){
    MainData.block.forEach(function(element,i,block){
      if(key == element.month){
        MainData.year.forEach(function(year, j, years){
          if(element.year == year && key == element.month){
           console.log("This is the Sale: ", element.Sale, "This is the year ", year, key);
            console.log(MainData.MonthRow[key], "This is the Month Key");
            console.log(MainData.MonthRow[key][year], "This is the year and key");
            MainData.MonthRow[key][year]=element.Sale;
            console.log(MainData.MonthRow)
          }
        })   
      }
    });
```

But after assigning the value using MonthRow[key][year]=element.Sale; it assigns the value to all the months.

My punctual question is how can I assign a value to  obj.key.year = value where key and year is a variable?

Recreated the in JSFiddle got the expected result, but on Sails frame work its not working

[JSFiddle Test](https://jsfiddle.net/6xkj73es/7/)

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between `MainData.MonthRow` and `MonthRow`? Which is the object shown at the top of your question? Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're using variables as object keys properly. `object[key][year]` would work, but only if `object[key]` already exists.

Comment: @Phil MainData.MonthRow and MonthRow are the same. I've tried using      MainData.MonthRow[key][year] = element.Sale; But I still get all back all the months assign the last value of the iteration

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense. In your question, you have both `MainData.MonthRow` and `MonthRow`. Where do you assign `MonthRow`? Are you having trouble producing a **Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example**?

Comment: Also, what is `MainData.block.`. Please, please please consider Phil's initial comment to you. Read the link.

Comment: This seems like a reference error, you've probably used the same object to initialise all the months in `MonthRow`. BTW, the code could be shorter as you don't need to loop `MonthRow`.

Comment: I tried reproducing this as best I could with the little information provided but could not see any problems ~ [JSFiddle reproduction](http://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/kojueb2g/5/)

Comment: @phil Thanks for the working example. I've updated the question

Comment: How are you initializing the `MonthRow` object? I bet there are some messed 
 up references there.

Comment: @Phil but those aren't images of code / data. They are images of console logs, which are fine.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in my console

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - The whole process is based on a couple of promises. The first gets the data from the DB, then creates the array MonthRow, then iterates through the block to assign the MonthRow value. I am creating the MonthRow like so MonthRow = {'1' : MainData.years, ...} and Im printing the object before I assign it to ensure the key does exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29050004/9867451) is that all sub-objects inside `MonthRow` are referencing the same object (`MainData.years`), in other words `MainData.years === MonthRow['1'] === MonthRow['2'] === ...`. So changes to one of those sub-objects will get reflected on all sub-objects, on `MainData.years` too. Here's a demonstration of the problem:

```js
var objA = {};

var objB = objA;            // objA is not copied to objB, only a reference is copied
                            // objA and objB are pointing/referencing the same object

objB.foo = "bar";           // changes to one of them ...

console.log(objA);          // ... are reflected on the other
```

To fix this, you need to clone the object `MainData.years` before assigning to each property of the object `MonthRow`, thus the sub-objects will all be different objects. You can use `Object.assign` for that like so:

```
MonthRow = {
  '1': Object.assign({}, MainData.years),
  '2': Object.assign({}, MainData.years),
  ...
}
```

**Side note:**

The code in the question can be refactored to a shorter one as you don't need to loop over the keys of `MonthRow` nor `MainData.year`, you only need to loop `MainData.block`, and for each element, you just check if the current element's year is included in `MainData.year` (using either `indexOf` or `includes`), and then update `MainData.MonthRow` using the element's year and month:

```
MainData.block.forEach(function(element) {
  if(MainData.year.indexOf(element.year) !== -1) {
    MainData.MonthRow[element.month][element.year] = element.sale;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The Object assignment was the issue.