# Deleting the full object despite the redefinition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Cannot figure out, why the `object innerMain` is getting smaller on every select change even though it gets redefined with `object main`’s structure in the beginning of the every call to the `trig()` function:

```
let innerMain = main;
```

```js
var main = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0
  };

$('#sel').on('change', function(){
  trig($(this));
});


function trig(th = false){
  let innerMain = main;

  delete innerMain[th.val()];
  console.log(innerMain);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Do you expect `let innerMain = main;` to create a _copy_ of `main`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change)

Comment: @SebastianSimon, yes kinda :/

Comment: Simple answer is there is only one object....the variables are *references* to the exact same object. `innerMain = main` *does not* make a copy

Comment: Try `let innerMain = Object.assign({}, main);` to create a quick copy of the object. Note that this works because all your keys in the original object are not objects themselves.

Comment: @mr.work Why not just declare `main` inside of `trig`? Do you actually need it outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens cuz you create new variable (`innerMain`) with reference to old (`main`) variable, and every time when you call delete, you call it for old variable (`main`)

So, you have only one variable and you modify it.

You should create new variable without reference.
How it works, you can read on **MDN**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Objects
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

**It works:**

```js
var main = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0
  };

$('#sel').on('change', function(){
  trig($(this));
});


function trig(th = false){
  let innerMain = Object.assign({}, main);

  delete innerMain[th.val()];
  console.log(innerMain);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Not to be _that_ guy, but the links point to MDN, not MSDN (Mozilla vs MicroSoft) :)