# why modifying variable value affecting unrelated variable

Tags: javascript

```
var data = '{"order_id":123,"order_status":"pending","items":{"111":{"id":111,"sku":"9876543","additional_sku":["11112345","111123457"],"qty":1,"name":"nama product 1"},"222":{"id":222,"sku":"4314143141","additional_sku":[],"qty":3,"name":"nama product 2"},"333":{"id":333,"sku":"524523423422","additional_sku":["22212345","222123457"],"qty":3,"name":"nama product 2"}}}';

var1 = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(var1['items']);  //log1
var2 = var1['items'];
var3 = var2;

//var3[111]['qty'] = 0;   //modify data line
console.log(var1['items'][111]['qty']);  //log2
console.log(var3[111]['qty']);  //log3
```

This is so weird:

1. why in log1 value of "var1['items'][111]['qty'] = 0"?? but when you comment/delete 'modify data line' the log1 shows "var1[111]['qty'] = 1". in log1 we havent modify anything yet. But the data is changed mysteriously. who change the data?
2. we change only var3 value, but why var1 value affected?

Comment: Because all of those variables point to the same object. Not only are they not "unrelated", they are literally the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change)

Comment: `var2` and `var3` point to the same memory location.

Comment: @ritaj and why in log1 it shows modified data? it not even modified yet there

Comment: It is modified. `var1`, `var2` and `var3` are the same thing.

Comment: @ritaj the modification happens in line 8. the logging happens on line 4. doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Chrome logs object references, so if their value changes you will see the new values, even if you logged before. Try logging `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(var1['items']))` instead.

Comment: @ritaj now that makes sense. thank you so much