# Unexpected mutation of object array

Tags: javascript

I have the following code (building my own little object-based-api...)

```
operator = {};

operator.set_data = function (json) {
    this.data = json
};

operator.first_load_chart = function () {
    let ref_data = operator.data;
    ref_data['date'] = ref_data['date'].map(x => x ? new Date(x * 1000) : null);
};
```

The `operator.first_load_chart` is run after `operator.data` is first assigned and `operator.data['date']` is first unix timestamps.

Yet when I run `console.log(operator.data['date'])` in console after `operator.first_load_chart` `operator.data['date]` has now changed to a `Date` object?

Why is this, and how can I prevent this mutation?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but one trick I use to find what's causing an unexpected mutation is to use `Object.freeze(operator)` after setting the objects data/value. After that, any attempt to mutate the object will throw an error at the offending line.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+object+copy+property+changes) of [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29050004/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let ref_data = operator.data
    ref_data['date'] = ref_data['date'].map(x => x ? new Date(x * 1000) : null)
```

Here the ref_data is getting a reference to the actual data in the operator. So when you modify the value using ref_data, you are in turn updating the actual data in operator itself. If this is not intended you should make a copy of the data object before modifying.

```
let ref_data = Object.assign({},operator.data);
 ref_data['date'] = ref_data['date'].map(x => x ? new Date(x * 1000) : null)
```

Be wary that this is not a deep copy, i.e. if you have nested object you will need to handle it  separtely.