# Changing the value on a JSON key changes another variable

Tags: javascript, object

I am sure there is an explanation for this but I cannot find it. The phenomenon I am facing is this:

```
const options = {"from":"0xa4cxxx","gasPrice":"0x2dc6c0","gas":"0x2dc6c0"};

let asd = options;
asd.from = "ZMY";

console.log("asd", asd);
console.log("options", options)
```

Prints:

```
asd {from: "ZMY", gasPrice: "0x2dc6c0", gas: "0x2dc6c0"}
options {from: "ZMY", gasPrice: "0x2dc6c0", gas: "0x2dc6c0"}
```

I am confused as to why this is changing the **const** variable too. What is the best way to change **asd** without changing the original **const options**  and why this is happening?

Comment: objects, arrays and classes are reference types, which means, they don't pass only the value, but the reference in the memory to it. So it doesn't matter where do you make changes, if it's a reference type, it will change in every variable that points to that reference.

Comment: yes @Reyno it does

Answer (score 2):

You only have one objects, but two references to it. If you want to do a (shallow) clone of the options object instead of referring to it, you can do

```
const options = {"from":"0xa4cxxx","gasPrice":"0x2dc6c0","gas":"0x2dc6c0"};

let asd = {...options};
asd.from = "ZMY";

console.log("asd", asd);
console.log("options", options)
```

Comment: Thank you, its working. Could you explain what the {...options} does, or provide a link please?

Comment: it is a spread operator. it creates a new object, {}, and assigns the properties of options object to the new object. You can read more here: https://codeburst.io/a-simple-guide-to-destructuring-and-es6-spread-operator-e02212af5831

Comment: found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change