# Sum values of nested objects without side-effects (reduce)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce, higher-order-functions, side-effects

I'm trying to sum nutritional values nested inside food objects:

```js
[
  {
    id: 'Potato',
    nutrition: [
      { id: 'PROT', val: 4 },
      { id: 'SUGAR', val: 1 }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'Banana',
    nutrition: [
      { id: 'FIB', val: 10 },
      { id: 'SUGAR', val: 4 }
    ]
  }
]
```

I use Array.prototype.reduce() to do so:

```js
foods.reduce((acc, { nutrition }) => {
    nutrition.map((x) => {
      let current = acc.find((y) => y.id === x.id)
      if (current) current.val += x.val
      else acc.push(x)
    })
  return acc
}, [])
```

This works, but it manipulates my original array and I cannot figure out why. I have tried to use the spread-operator and let/var but to no avail. How can I achieve what I want without side-effects?

Comment: "*it manipulates my original array and I cannot figure out why.*" -> `current.val += x.val`

Comment: @VLAZ okay but how can I create a copy of the food object then? I though "let current" would create a copy

Comment: It doesn't. `a = {}; b = a` means there is a single object and both `a` and `b` point to it. Manipulating one, "changes" the other. Well, since they are both literally the same object, you only change one.

Comment: See [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29050004/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` and `forEach` and take `Object.values` in last, something like this:

```js
const foods = [ { id: 'Potato', nutrition: [ { id: 'PROT', val: 4 }, { id: 'SUGAR', val: 1 } ] }, { id: 'Banana', nutrition: [ { id: 'FIB', val: 10 }, { id: 'SUGAR', val: 4 } ] }];

const result = Object.values(foods.reduce((a,{nutrition})=>{
    nutrition.forEach(({id, val})=>{
        (a[id] ??= {id, val:0}).val+=val;
    });
    return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Could you explain (how can I read) '??='? I assume that it's a quick way of creating a key if there is none but have never seen it before so I am not sure.

Comment: @howtopythonpls this is logical nullish assignment, you can read about it more here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Answer (score 1):

You can first make use of `forEach` instead of `map` since there is no need of `map` to return a new array in your use-case and fix the above by making a copy of `x` when pushing to the `acc` array like so :-

```
foods.reduce((acc, { nutrition }) => {
    nutrition.forEach((x) => {
      let current = acc.find((y) => y.id === x.id)
      if (current) current.val += x.val
      else acc.push({...x})
    })
  return acc
}, [])
```

Comment: Cheers, I already marked an answer but this is equally helpful!

Comment: @VLAZ I don't think it will because that `current` is pointing to **object** that exists at an index inside the `acc` array and not from `nutrition`.

Comment: You're right. I misread the code - sorry.