# Spread operator in array syntax Vs. Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

New to React.

I was trying to update the boolean value 'done' whenever the user clicks on it.

For some reasons, this code doesn't work

```
var updateTodo = todos;
updateTodo[Number(id)].done = !updateTodo[Number(id)].done;
setTodos(updateTodo);
```

but this does

```
var updateTodo = [...todos];
updateTodo[Number(id)].done = !updateTodo[Number(id)].done;
setTodos(updateTodo);
```

As far as I think `todos` and `[...todos]` both return the same values i.e. todos array, then why won't the first code snippet work?

Here is working `App.tsx` for reference, not working snippet present in the function `handleDone`.

```
import React from "react";

type item = {
  itemId: number;
  todo: string;
  done: boolean;
};

var id = 0;

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState<item[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setNewTodo(value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    setTodos([...todos, { itemId: id, todo: newTodo, done: false }]);
    id++;
    setNewTodo("");
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleDone = (item: any) => {
    // Not Working
    var updateTodo = todos;
    updateTodo[Number(id)].done = !updateTodo[Number(id)].done;
    setTodos(updateTodo);

    // Working Code
    // var updateTodo = [...todos];
    // updateTodo[Number(id)].done = !updateTodo[Number(id)].done;
    // setTodos(updateTodo);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input onChange={handleChange} value={newTodo} type="text" name="todo" placeholder="Enter Todo" />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((item, index) => {
          return item.done ? (
            <li id={`${item.itemId}`} onClick={handleDone} style={{ textDecoration: "line-through" }}>
              {item.todo}
            </li>
          ) : (
            <li id={`${item.itemId}`} onClick={handleDone} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
              {item.todo}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: `foo = arr`, then `foo` evaluates to the *same array object* as `arr`. `foo = [...arr]`, then foo is a *new array* created via a *shallow copy* and changing `foo` (eg. adding or removing an element) does not affect `arr`. Returning or passing a value has the *the same behavior in this regard as an assignment* (that is, no copy/clone is created implicitly). Sometimes both are ok. Sometimes using the same object is necessary. Sometimes a copy is required for proper behavior. It really depends on what later modifies the array (or arrays) and what the expectations are.

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Most likely duplicate of [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29050004/4642212).

Comment: To reiterate, both of these are mutations of state and neither is ok.  But the second case causes a re-render because `updateTodo` is a different array whereas in the first case you are setting the state to itself.