# Can someone explain to me what's wrong? - sort by height

Tags: javascript

I don't know why the code skips some numbers some times. For case `4: a: [4, 2, 9, 11, 2, 16]` my output is `[2, 4, 2, 9, 11, 16]` when the expected output is `[2, 2, 4, 9, 11, 16]`.

I'm not modifying the index array so it should check every number position's. Also, I'm not sure how line 7 completely works, in position j it's added the elimination of the element i? If so why is there an [0] behind?

I find this code kind of messy but I need to learn from it.

```
function sortByHeight(a) {
    r = a
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i]!= -1) {
            for(j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[j] != -1 && a[i] - a[j] < 0) {
                    r.splice(j,0,r.splice(i,1)[0])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return r
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)? Is this a learning experience on manually writing sorting algorithms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change)

Comment: That's a poor choice of code to learn from. It's a very inefficient sorting algorithm, and it's badly-implemented. Local variables are not declared.

Comment: It's because you are using `splice()` on the original array which is destructive. You'll need create a new array and populate it instead.

Comment: If you are not sure how it works (or why it doesn't), split it into a bit smaller chunks (for example putting the "nested" splice into a separate variable) and then use a debugger to walk through the code line by line as it executes and look at all the variables and how they change on each step

Comment: Briefly answering to all of you. I'm not using sort because that would change the whole array. I want the ```-1``` to stay put wherever they are. 
I don't think forgetting to write ```let``` makes this not suitable for learning from, maybe you are on another level. 
The intention wasn't to use splice() on the original array, I thought I had made a copy. Thanks for the comments though.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is probably thinking that `r = a` copies the array. That's not the case in JavaScript. JavaScript works by reference, meaning that every value *(apart from primitives such as numbers)* are actually references. Therefore, `r` and `a` point to the exact same array in memory. Modifying one also "modifies the other", so to speak.

You can clone the array by doing one of the following:

```js
r = [ ...a ];
r = a.slice();
r = Array.from(a);
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me this, I had forgotten. The thing is the code actually works worse now hahah, I'll wait for more help I guess.

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in this line `(a[j] - a[i] < 0)`, you checking it for `(a[i] - a[j] < 0)`,
checking in the reverse order will give you the array in decreasing order, you can reverse the array before returning will give you it in increasing order

```
function sortByHeight(a) {
r = a
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i]!= -1) {
        for(j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[j] != -1 && (a[j] - a[i] < 0)) {
                r.splice(j,0,r.splice(i,1)[0])
            }
        }
    }
}
r.reverse()
return r
}
```

Comment: No, I don't know why you think ```(a[j] - a[i] < 0)``` makes any difference. Actually the splice positions don't make sense that way, that's not the problem.