# Value overwriting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I created an object const with a data and I made other const from the first. But my problem is when I change the second object, my first const also is changed.

Have a method to resolve this?

```js
const user1 = {
  name: "samuel"
}

const user2 = user1;

user2.name = "guedes";

console.log(user1); //output: "guedes"
console.log(user2); //output: "guedes"
```

Comment: You don't have two objects. It's only one object in total with two labels pointing to it.

Comment: You probably want to look into using a class.

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript :)

What you're doing here is creating a reference to user1, and then changing user1.name via the user2 reference.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change

Comment: @jsonp It's not just JS - `a = b` will not *clone* an object in a lot of languages. Same thing happens in Java or C#, for example = you get a second variable but still one object.

Comment: @VLAZ Interesting. I haven't touched C# in like 11 years. I thought it was one of those JavaScript quirks like `typeof NaN === 'number'`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use es6

```js
const user1 = {
  name: "samuel"
}

const user2 = {...user1};

user2.name = "guedes";

console.log(user1); //output: "guedes"
console.log(user2); //output: "guedes"
```

Comment: Just be careful with nested data, otherwise there will be data loss. OP's scenario (like epascarello said) looks like it requires a User class. But see this thread on deep copying objects:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript