# I'm trying to stop a constant dictionary from being modified in a function

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm writing a JavaScript University building indoor map program, and the displaying route code works, however my dictionary which stores the graph is being changed within the function and I don't have much experience in JavaScript and can't spot the problem.

this is the Dictionary;

```
const TheGraph = {
    "A" : { 
        "Coordinates" : [3776, 625],
        "Links" : {"C": 1}
    },
    "B" : { 
        "Coordinates" : [970, 910],
        "Links" : {"C" : 5, "G" : 5}
    },
    ....

}
```

And this is where i believe is the problem

```
button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        var possRoutes = []; // stores the points
        const lineString = new H.geo.LineString();
        var heading = (document.getElementById('room-header')).innerHTML 
        var heading = heading.substring(5); // gets the name of the room
        for (const x of (Rooms[heading][1])){
            possRoutes.push(findShortestPath(TheGraph, "A", x))
        } // finds the shorted path
        possRoutes.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
            return prev.distance < curr.distance ? prev : curr;
        });
        for (var cor in possRoutes[0].path){
            var point = TheGraph[point = possRoutes[0].path[cor]].Coordinates // gets the coordinate from the dictionary
            var distanceToOrigin = pythagorean(point[1], point[0])//maths
            var ang = 1.5708-(angle + Math.atan(point[0]/point[1]))
            point[0] = originX-(Math.cos(ang)*distanceToOrigin)*scaleX
            point[1] = originY-(Math.sin(ang)*distanceToOrigin)*scaleY
            lineString.pushPoint({lat: point[0], lng: point[1]}) // adds the point to the map
        }
        point = Rooms[heading][0]
        var distanceToOrigin = pythagorean(point[1], point[0])
        var ang = 1.5708-(angle + Math.atan(point[0]/point[1]))
        point[0] = originX-(Math.cos(ang)*distanceToOrigin)*scaleX
        point[1] = originY-(Math.sin(ang)*distanceToOrigin)*scaleY
        lineString.pushPoint({lat: point[0], lng: point[1]})
        console.log(TheGraph)
        path = new H.map.Polyline(
            lineString, { style: { lineWidth: 4,
                strokeColor: '#2600ff' }}
        )
        F0.addObject(path);//displays the route on the map
    })
```

Comment: How is a variable defined as `const` being changed after its initial value? Aside: In Javascript, the `const` keyword makes it impossible to change its value after the fact.

Comment: @mardubbles It isn't; `point` refers to an object in `TheGraph` and `point` is modified directly.

Comment: `var point = TheGraph[point = possRoutes[0].path[cor]].Coordinates` looks sketchy. And then you are modifying the properties of that `point`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my problem.

`var point = Object.assign({}, point);`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29050089/18367450

Answer (score 0):

const means that the name `theGraph` cannot be reassigned to refer to something else, not that the thing it refers to is immutable. You’re changing the elements in the coordinates array in the lines that start with `point[0]` etc.