# Why is this function inside the constructor referencing an object instance even though it's not a property?

Tags: javascript, promise

```
function Promise (callback){

    //this = {}
    //because of "new" keyword, an empty object is automatically created, and the "this" is referencing to that object.
    
   this.status = "pending";

   const resolve = () => {
            this.status = "fulfilled";
            console.log("status is: " + this.status)    
    };
  
    callback(resolve);
    
    //return this 
    // at the end, javascript automatically returns the "this" object.
}

console.log("start")

const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 3000);
});

setTimeout(() => console.log(p1.status), 4000)

//output:
 //start
 //status is: fulfilled
 //fulfilled
```

So now, p1 is an object instance of Promise.

After the "`this`" object is returned to the p1 variable, the `resolve` function is yet to be executed, and after 3 seconds, it then executes.

The `resolve` function is not a property or method of an object because it's not written as this.resolve(){...} or Promise.prototype.resolve()....

**My question is**: When the `resolve` function is passed in the callback: `callback(resolve)`, the "**this**" inside the `resolved` function is referencing the **newly created object** : `this = {}` and **not** the **p1** object?

but when the `resolve` function is invoked, it changes the status of p1. So it's `this` is actually referencing to the p1 object. Why is that? I'm confused.

...and even if I make it like this:

```
this.resolve = () => {
            this.status = "fulfilled";
            console.log("status is: " + this.status)      
    };
  
callback(this.resolve);
```

the **this** in the `this.resolve` will still be referencing the **newly created object**: `this = {}` from what I understand.

The code above is from: [https://medium.com/swlh/implement-a-simple-promise-in-javascript](https://medium.com/swlh/implement-a-simple-promise-in-javascript-20c9705f197a#:%7E:text=When%20creating%20a%20Promise%2C%20the,are%20passed%20to%20the%20handler.)

I just modified it.

Comment: I don't get how you distinguish "*the newly created object : `this = {}` and […] the `p1` object*"? They are **the same** object. Just bound to multiple identifiers.

Comment: and yet, if you make `function resolve () {` rather than `const resolve = () => {` it all fails - the apparent magic here is how `this` works in an arrow function (unless I misunderstood your confusion)

Comment: I have a feeling your misunderstanding is caused by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't think [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6?rq=3) is what the question is about, OP seems to be clear on that `this` inside `resolve` is the same as `this` in the surrounding constructor scope

Comment: he seems to be confused about what `this` is though - `the this in the this.resolve will still be referencing ...`

Comment: Well, it's a combination of all of the above. "`this`" and `p1` are the same object. `this` inside the `resolve` function persists because of closures and arrow-function preservation of `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow function declaration of `resolve()` captures the lexical value of `this` at the point of the function declaration.  Because that lexical value of `this` is the `this` inside the constructor, it will naturally point to the newly created object that was created by that constructor.

That lexical value of `this` is hardwired into that specific declaration of `resolve` (that's how arrow functions work).

Note, that each running of the Promise constructor creates a NEW copy of the resolve function with a different lexical `this` bound to it.

This "binding of the lexical this" is a very important feature of arrow functions and would not be the case if you did `function resolve() {}` instead.

> My question is: When the resolve function is passed in the callback: callback(resolve), the "this" inside the resolved function is referencing the newly created object : this = {} and not the p1 object?

But, `p1` and `this` inside the `resolve()` function are the same object.  They are the same object.  You can attach a unique property to one and you will see it on the other.  Or you can compare them directly.  They are the same object.

Comment: Yes I know what you meant, but the wording was ambiguous. Thanks for the clarification edit!