# Duplicate item from array then change id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to duplicate an item with splice but I got problems while changing id. I need different ID for each items but while duplicate, it keeps the same id. Also the id become a number but should be a string.

```
const duplicateCard = (index, listId) => {
    const list = data.lists[listId];
    const duplicate_item = list.cards[index];
    duplicate_item["id"] = list.cards.length + 1;
    list.cards.splice(0, 0, duplicate_item);
    const newState = {
      ...data,
      lists: {
        ...data.lists,
        [listId]: list,
      },
    };
    setData(newState);
    window.localStorage.setItem("datt", JSON.stringify(newState));
  };
```

Output: The item is duplicated but id is changed for both same items and it becomes integer instead of string

Comment: `const duplicate_item = list.cards[index]; duplicate_item["id"] = list.cards.length + 1;`  you are changing the id original item here is that intended? u can maybe make a shallow copy like `const duplicate_item = {...list.cards[index]};` but cannot say if shallow copy is enough without seeing the data structure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change

Comment: @cmgchess Seems to work with your suggestion! thank you

Comment: cool u can post answer maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`splice` is a mutable action. In React, you always construct *new* data -

```js
const duplicateCard = (index, listId) => {
  setData(data => {
    const list = data.lists[listId]
    return {
      ...data,
      lists: {
        ...data.lists,
        [listId]: {
          ...list,
          cards: [
            {
              ...list.cards.at(index),
              id: list.cards.length // you need better id generator
            },
            ...list.cards,
          ]
        },
    },
  })
}
```

Quite a state nightmare you've created for yourself!

You could try to manage it with generic function like `update` -

```js
function update(key, func) {
  return t => { switch (t.constructor) {
    case Array:
      return [...t.slice(0, key), func(t.at(key), key, t), ...t.slice(key + 1)]
    case Object:
      return {...t, [key]: func(t[key], key, t)}
    default:
      throw Error(`update called on non-object: ${t}`)
  }}
}
```

Now your `duplicateCard` function can be improved. Note `newId` is a responsibility of the caller -

```js
const duplicateCard = (index, listId, newId) => {
  setData(
    update("lists",
      update(listId,
        update("cards", cards => [
          { ...cards.at(index), id: newId },
          ...cards,
        ])
      )
    )
  )
}
```

It's a big step in the right direction, and maybe you can see a pattern emerging. Still it seems like a lot of effort.

It turns out immutable data structures have  well-designed and tested tools to work with them. See libraries like [ImmutableJS](https://immutable-js.com).

Answer (score 1):

As @cmgchess suggests, this is working:

```
const duplicateCard = (index, listId) => {
    const list = data.lists[listId];
    const duplicate_item = {...list.cards[index]};
    duplicate_item["id"] = (list.cards.length + 1).toString();
    list.cards.splice(0, 0, duplicate_item);
    const newState = {
      ...data,
      lists: {
        ...data.lists,
        [listId]: list,
      },
    };
    setData(newState);
    window.localStorage.setItem("datt", JSON.stringify(newState));
  };
```